# how to recieve multiple values in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i have a page practice.php and addtocart.php.From practice2.php i am trying to send multiple data to addtocart.php.However i do not know how to retrive multiple data seperately.Here are my codes:

```
 practice2.php
   function addtocart(price){
var productdetails=document.forms['mehendicones'].value;
var pcolor=document.getElementByClassName('mehendi_color').value;
var pquantity=document.getElementById('quantity_mehendi_color').value;
var bal=price*pquantity;
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST","addtocart.php",true)
```

ajax.send("productdetails="+productdetails+"&pcolor="+pcolor+"&pquantity="+pquantity+"&price="+price+"&bal="+bal);

```
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200){
        alert(this.responseText);
            }
        }

    }


     addtocart.php
       if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
        $uname=file_get_contents("php://input");
                    $pdetails=//i dont know how to retrieve it seperately           
                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't POST data without including a `Content-Type` header on the request to state what kind of data it is.

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Then PHP will be able to parse it and populate `$_POST` with the data so you don't have to read it from STDIN.

Comment: yes but how do i retrieve the data in the second page?

Comment: @TasneemEdoo — I refer you back to the last paragraph of this answer.